# Do they make anti-parallel diodes in 2-lead packages?

Tags: diodes, diode-clamp

Sometimes diodes in an anti-parallel configuration are used on the inputs to high-gain instrumentation amplifiers in order to protect against large differential voltages.

Does anyone know if the industry produces 2-pin packages in this kind of configuration? If so, what is the name of this configuration?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDpfaG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Not that I've seen. You'll have to make do with 3-pin common cathode or common anode versions.

Comment: for higher voltage you also use back to back zeners

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a [BAV99](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BAV99_SER.pdf) and connect pins 1 and 2 together.

[image]

If a lower voltage is desired (and the leakiness is not an issue) you can use a common dual Schottky such as [BAT54S](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85508/bat54.pdf), as @RohatKılıç suggests. The package is the same as the BAV99.

There are dual [back-to-back LEDs](https://www.kingbright.com/attachments/file/psearch/000/00/00/L-57IID(Ver.14A).pdf) available, which exactly meets your request, however a red one would limit at more like +/-2V than +/-700mV for the BAV99 or +/-300mV for the BAT54S. The visual indication might be useful.

[image]

Comment: Or BAT54S, alternatively.

Comment: I've thought about doing that, but the problem with 3-pin devices is that you could unbalance the positive and negative terminals on the opamp. The best I've been able to find is a 6 pin package that has two isolated diodes, each pointing in the opposite direction.

Comment: @sgdsgyhetwaraw Isolated diodes are more likely to be mis-matched. Maybe just the occasional one.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That is a good point I didn't think of. I'm guessing mismatched diodes would have more of an "unbalancing" effect than the extra pad, espeically on an already small package.